# How is Experience handled in Dragon Age?

Tags: dragon-age-origins

How is it distributed to the characters?
Do dead characters get experience?
Do characters not in the current party get experience?
Does the character who actually kills the enemy get more experience?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Experience gives a lot of info on experience in Dragon Age. Characters are given experience for their individual actions, and experience is not shared between party members.

Actions that give experience:

- Killing an enemy (only the final blow
  counts)
- Completing quests
- Picking a lock (if successful)
- Disarming a trap (if successful)
- Acquiring a new codex entry
- Donating to your allies

So, to answer the questions in order based on the info in the wiki page:

- Experience is distributed to individuals, not among party members, who perform one of the above tasks
- Dead characters do not gain experience because they do not perform any of the above actions; however, their level is automatically adjusted to one level below the Warden's once you return to camp if they are two or more levels below his level
- Unused party members do not gain experience; rather, their level is adjusted to be one below the Warden's under the same conditions as dead characters
- The character who actually kills the enemy is the only one who gets experience.

Comment: To add to this, you get more experience the higher the game difficulty level.

Comment: What does "donating to allies" mean - special scripted occurrences, or an action that can be done at any time? I am about 25% through the game, and didn't notice this.

Comment: @NPC After you finish completing the quests for an ally race (elves, humans, etc.) you can donate gold or items to their representatives in your camp.  The more you donate, the more experience you gain.  There's no indication of experience being gained other than the experience bar on the screen, and it's a neat way to turn unwanted items into (a little) experience.

Comment: "The character who actually kills the enemy is the only one who gets experience." That is actually not true, everyone in the current party gets the same exp. I checked this as well with trap disarming, which was also distributed to the whole party.

Comment: @eL13 Oh, lame. :< uhhhhhh

Comment: Right now my main character just gained a level after a fight although he was dead! Ugh, this wiki seems to be pretty wrong :( I will mark this question unanswered temporarily, probably someone can help?

Comment: The wiki appears to have been updated.  It now shows that other characters in the party will receive 2 less xp than the character who performs the action.